# Facet LDA graph - R

Tags: r

Is it possible to facet the graph below to 3 different graphs based on species?

Code:

```
require(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
data(iris)

irisLda <- lda(iris[,-5],iris[,5])


irisLda <- lda(Species~.,data=iris)
plot(irisLda)       
irisProjection <- cbind(scale(as.matrix(iris[,-5]),scale=FALSE) %*% irisLda$scaling,iris[,5,drop=FALSE])
p <- ggplot(data=irisProjection,aes(x=LD1,y=LD2,col=Species))+ geom_point(size =5)  
p
```

Comment: Does adding `+ facet_wrap(vars(Species))` to your plot definition give you what you want?  if not, please explain why not.  `+ facet_grid(cols=vars(Species))` also seems to work.